# API Blueprint - How to perform a simple UPDATE

Tags: api, rest, apiblueprint, apiary

I have went through the documentation of Apiary but did not find out how to create a blue print to update a resource.

What I am trying to achieve here is a simple scenario such as having a list of users, being able to list them, retrieve a single user by id, define different attributes for that user, modify one-n attributes of that user (updating that user), and delete that user.

Could someone redirect me to some clear documentation or to a stackoverflow question that I have missed during my research and that would help me achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use `PUT` or `PATCH` method for update resource. Look into this [blog post](http://blog.apiary.io/2014/01/09/Inspirational-Resources/) here are some examples.

Comment: If found some example with PATCH operation. Thank you. However, I am wondering if maybe I don't understand what Apiary is supposed to do. My idea was that you could define in a blue print a set of data that would be returned when you would list users for example. But, if you delete a user with a given id, is the user going to be removed from the data set?

Comment: Not in apiary mock. Apiary use only blueprint data, not database.

Comment: Do you know anything else that I could use to quickly design an API online and perform basic CRUD operations? I need to be able to modify some attributes of a resources and be able to see the modification reflected in my view.